# Setting values in s:select using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to reset the values on a page using an ajax call.
I am using Jquery to perform this.

The values have to be  reseted in a multi-select list.

If I change the value in the select box and click on reset then the last saved values from DB have to be set in the list.

I am trying the below

```
            function resetNameDetails() {

                            $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: 'resetNameDetailsAction.action?,
                                            error: function(data) {
                                                            alert("error");
                                            },
                                            success: function(data) {

                                                            alert("sucess");
                                                            alert(data.userModel.nameList);

                                            }
                            });

            }
```

The second alert in success gives a list of Objects only. How I transfer this data to the select control.

---

Update

```
var nameListData = data.userModel.nameList; 
var select = document.getElementById('nameList'); 
alert(select); 
select.options.length = 0; // clear out existing items 
for(var i=0; i < nameListData.length; i++) { 
  var d = nameListData[i]; 
  alert(d); 
  select.options.add(new Option(d, i)) 
}
```

shows me the list populated with [Object object]

Comment: Is your `data.userModel.nameList` an array? or an object? what is its structure?

Comment: Can you give an example of the returned data?

Comment: The tried the below  var nameListData = data.userModel.nameList;
  
  
  var select = document.getElementById('nameList');
  alert(select);
  select.options.length = 0; // clear out existing items
  for(var i=0; i < nameListData.length; i++) {
      var d = nameListData[i];
      alert(d);
      select.options.add(new Option(d, i))
  }
It shows me the list populated with [Object object]  ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `data.userModel.nameList` is an array of values, you can do this:

```
...
success: function(data) {
   var values = data.userModel.nameList;
   $(":checkbox").each(function(){
      var value = $(this).attr("value");
      if($.inArray(value, values))
          $(this).attr("checked", true);
      else
          $(this).attr("checked", false);
   });    
}
...
```

**EDIT**: That was for checkboxes list. For a multi-select, do this:

```
...
    success: function(data) {
       var values = data.userModel.nameList;
       $("#your_select option").each(function(){
          var value = $(this).attr("value");
          if($.inArray(value, values))
              $(this).attr("selected", true);
          else
              $(this).attr("selected", false);
       });    
    }
...
```

Hope this helps. Cheers