# How to set values in multi Select from ajax response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, multi-select

```js
function getNamefromDb(){
  var dataString = "metodo=getNames";
  
  $.ajax({
   type : "GET",
   url : "NameList.do",
   data : dataString,
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success : function(data) {
          if (data.success == false) {
         swal({
            title: data.message,
            html: true,
           
          });
         console.log("Fail"+data.message);
        } else {
         console.log("Success");
         $.each(JSON.parse(data.message), function(key, value) {
          $('#selectBoxId').append($("<option/>", {
                 value: key,
                 text: value
             }));
         });
         $("#selectBoxId").multiselect('rebuild');
        }
          }
      }); 
  }
```

```html
 <select id="selectBoxId" multiple="multiple"  onclick="javascript:getNamefromDb();">
```

Here I am receiving the json response from the ajax call. And then I had to set those values to the select box. Is it possible?
But anyhow the function getNamefromDb() is not called. Please tell what's wrong in it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5879736/7124761

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
  let dropdown = document.getElementById('selectBoxId');
    if (data.success){
    const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    let option;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = data[i].value;
      option.value = data[i].key;
      dropdown.add(option);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectBoxId').change(function() {
    var dataString = "{metodo:getNames,value:$(this).val()};
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "NameList.do",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json"
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                data = response;
                return response;
            },
            if (data.success == false) {


                swal({
                    title: data.message,
                    html: true,

                });
                console.log("Fail" + data.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Success");
                $.each(JSON.parse(data.message), function(key, value) {
                    $('#selectBoxId').append($("<option/>", {
                        value: key,
                        text: value
                    }));
                });
                $("#selectBoxId").multiselect('rebuild');
            }
        }
    });
```

}